# ngx-leaflet angular 5 map tiles issue when using production build

Tags: angular, leaflet, ngx-leaflet

I'm pretty new to Angular and built my first angular app with leaflet plugin. All is working as expected until using production build:

`ng s --target=production`
or
`ng build --target=production`

The leaflet map container shows not all map-tiles and/or in wrong row, column. I tried to force the map redraw with map.invalidateSize(); in onMapReady(..) but with no success.

`(leafletMapReady)="onMapReady($event)`

the component itself is showed depending on *ngIf condition:

```
<div>
    <app-tracking-map *ngIf="deliveryState == 1" [trackingData]="trackingData"></app-tracking-map>
</div>
```

I actually have no clue where to start the investigation just guess it's related to webpack and the magic bundling stuff.

in angular-cli.json I have added the leaflet css

```
      "styles": [
    "styles.css",
    "../node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css"
  ],
```

Comment: Sounds like missing the Leaflet CSS file. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48579677/leaflet-map-not-sizing-to-dimensions-of-target-element/48579921#48579921

Comment: As @ghybs said, it's likely missing leaflet.css. The ngx-leaflet README talks about some different ways to include the css file depending on your build system: https://github.com/Asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet#import-the-leaflet-stylesheet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are likely missing the leaflet.css file located in `./node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css`. When that is missing, the map and tiles are drawn, but they aren't laid out properly.

How you reference the file in your Webpack build depends on how you have your project set up. The ngx-leaflet README file describes some of the most common configurations:

https://github.com/Asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet#import-the-leaflet-stylesheet

Comment: thanks @reblace pointed me to the right direction. Forgot initially to mention that I had the leaflet css reference in the angular-cli.json - see edited question. Finally and that solved my issue for now I added the leaflet.css in the src/style.css
    `@import "~leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";`
not sure if this is the right place. The ngx-leaflet README is talking about a vendor.ts file when using webpack - but I do not have such file in the current angular 5 project.
thanks again!

Comment: I'm not sure if you saw this: https://www.asymmetrik.com/ngx-leaflet-tutorial-angular-cli/ It's a tutorial that walks you through getting Leaflet working with ng-cli and there's a GitHub repo with a working example. Shows how to get the css and stuff set up correctly.

Comment: It is worth to mention that angular.json (where you adds style's path) is not in watch mode with `ng serve`. To see changes you need to run `ng serve` one more time.